# Angularjs filter isn't working with json data

Tags: json, angularjs

I'm using simple Angularjs filter where you can filter items in the list with the help of input. I put the code here http://plnkr.co/edit/6vDeOiGNGbblkCBOi8B7?p=preview Filter does work as intended, but if I move data from controller to json and then parse it like that

```
function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('companies.json').success(function(data) {
         $scope.companies = data;
};
```

Json data renders in the ng-repeat list, but filter search doesn't work anymore. How can I apply filter with json data?

I also added json file I wanted to use to the same plunker.

Comment: What's wrong with your filter?, it seems to me that it's working just fine.

Comment: you are passing a big object not an array in companies.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your json file is an object instead of an array. So you'd better change it to an array, or

```
myApp.controller('CompaniesController', ['$http', '$scope', 
  function($http,$scope) {
    $http.get('companies.json').success(function(data) {
        var companies = [];
        // make the object to an array
        for(var companyName in data) {
          companies.push(data[companyName]);
        }
         $scope.companies = companies;
    });
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply turn it to array with [toArray](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#toarray) filter of [angular.filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter) module.
**Usage:** `object | toArray: addKey[optional]`

***Note:*** if `addKey` set to true,the filter also attaches a new property $key to the value containing the original key that was used in the object we are iterating over to reference the property.
**Example:**

```
  <input ng-model="model" type="text"/>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="comp in companies | toArray | filter:model">
      {{ comp }}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about this possibility. I should definitely dive into filters more carefully.